# Invoke method on generic type?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe

Why does the following generate an error in Delphi (XE)?

```
unit UTest;

interface


type

TTest = class
  public
  procedure Foo<T>(A: T);
end;

implementation

{ TTest }

procedure TTest.Foo<T>(A: T);
begin
  A.Add('hej');
end;

end.
```

I thought that generic types in Delphi was simply inserted into the generic function, so it would only error out if used with a type which don't have an Add(string) method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code produces a compilation error because the compiler has no way of knowing that `T` has a method named `Add` that receives a single string parameter.

> I thought that generic types in Delphi was simply inserted into the generic function, so it would only error out if used with a type which don't have an Add(string) method.

If you were using Smalltalk or C++ templates, then your assumption would be accurate. However, generics are not the same as templates. For generics you need to apply a constraint to the type parameter. The constraint needs to tell the compiler what properties `T` must have.

For example, you could constrain `T` to be derived from a class that has a suitable `Add` method. Or you could constrain `T` to implement an interface with a suitable `Add` method.

Documentation link for Delphi generic constraints: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics

The generic constraints that can be applied are rather limited, which is something of a shame. For example, I'd love to be able to constrain a type to have certain mathematical operators. For example, I'd like to be able to constrain a type to have `+` and `-` operators, say. However, there are pros and cons to both generics and templates, and so I do accept that these limitations are the result of a justifiable design decision by the Delphi language designers.

Comment: The reason I want to do the above is that I have two classes which do not share a base class (or interface) but some method signatures are exactly the same. I guess this isn't possible with the limited constraints?

Comment: That is correct. If these were templates you'd be fine. But you are simply out of luck with generics. You've hit the same problem that stops me writing nice mathematical algorithms that can operate on both scalar and complex values.

Comment: That's too bad :( I guess I'll have to revert to RTTI and if-statements (blersh).

Comment: @monoceres then add an interface containing the property definition of the `Add` method, use it as an interface constraint on `T`, and implement that interface in both classes. See https://bitbucket.org/jeroenp/besharp.net/commits/52b8721b5115724d51cdfae8bfed613028bdd285

Comment: The classes are auto-generated from WSDL (soap). I don't think it's very good to be messing with them.